# Mapping "Paste" to middle mouse button " in Notepad++ with plugin? instead of Ctrl+V

Tags: notepad++, hotkeys

Long story short my hands kill me when having to keep my fingers cramped together (WASD).

I would like to map my middle mouse button (the scroll wheel) to "paste" instead of Ctrl+V in Notepad++. Is there a possible way to do this using a plug-in or maybe something similar to notepad++ (the color scheme with different code is mainly the feature I like)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Plugin called MultiClipboard, it offers Paste via middle button . You find it in the [NPP Plugin List](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/nppPluginList) . (At the end of the linked Document there are two links to the 32 or 64 bit Plugins. MultiClipboard seems to be available only in 32bit.)

Comment: Broken link. Dead plugin?

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the hint. I updated the answer to the new plugin list.